# How do I get this chart to interperet my time scale?

Tags: c#, .net, charts

Ok, so I have my chart, working pretty well and plotting what I need. It's using .net charts, the ones that are available in visual studio by default.

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
{
    series1.Points.AddXY(d[i], g[i]);
}
```

I need it to interpret these dates correctly. At the moment it is plotting each at a set distance regardless of the actual time-scale.

E.g. If I have 5 data points, 4 on the 1st Jan, and one on the 5th of Jan, it will plot them at an equal distance when there should be a larger gap between the 1st Jan and 2nd of Jan. Hope that makes sense. Please ignore the awful grid-lines.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks

Edit:
`chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;` is used as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to set the IntervalType inside the asp:Chart tag ?

```
<AxisX>
    <LabelStyle Format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" IntervalType="Days"  Interval="1"/>
</AxisX>
```

See here for more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934284.aspx

I came across the XValueType property, maybe that would work as opposed to the XAxis one?
See here for more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.series.xvaluetype.aspx

Comment: Yes. I am using C# also. 

`chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;`

Comment: Sorry I would have thought that the IntervalType or IntervalOffsetType would have worked. Where are you calling the code to set these properties on the chart? Page_Load() ?

Comment: Last attempt, have you tried the XValueType property? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.series.xvaluetype.aspx